# In detecting duplicate code, how to compare one file with multiple files

Tags: code-duplication

We have one file to be detected and there is a project with multiple files, then we want to know whether there is duplicate code between this file and the files in the project.

We have tried some tools like Simian, but this tool is used to detect all files in a project (all files compare each other).

As you can see, what we want to do is comparing one file with multiple files in the project, not comparing all files with each other.

Comment: you can use comparison tool like *Beyond compare* ,winmerge etc. I prefer you  to use Beyond compare  as I using it for a while and it never disappointed me while comparing wheter single file with specific file or with whole project folder.

Comment: @Virender singh Rathore Thank you. I have read the introduction of these softwares, but these softwares seem like being used to compare text files, not code files. For example, if there are some variable names changed, it might can not be detected as duplicate code.